# What format should time parameter in a request to google cloud API have?

Tags: google-maps

I can't seem to find the guidelines about the appropriate format of [time parameter in a request to Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#departure_time) and whenenever I pass anything that is not "now", I get a "Bad Request" response. I have tried a timestamp, "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999" and other dates in the same format. Should it be a timestamp? Some kind of datetime string?

Comment: ***You can specify the time as an integer in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.*** - What exactly is unclear from that second sentence in the documentation you linked to?

Comment: Apologies - completely missed that. I'm deleting the post.